# Adding Image to JWindow via JLabel not Appearing on the Screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jwindow

I am trying to create a splash screen for a risk game that I am developing. For some reason the splash screen doesnt appear even though I am adding it to the Jwindow, I would appreciate an expert eye that will see what I can't. Thanks in  advance

```
/new jWindow as it is better for splash screen as there is no borders
        JWindow window = new JWindow();
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/riskimage.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
        window.getContentPane().add(label);
        window.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 100);
        window.setVisible(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        window.setVisible(false);
        
        // title of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Risk");

        //Creating a text field
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JLabel welcome = new JLabel("");
        welcome.setFont (welcome.getFont ().deriveFont (20.0f));
        welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 1 in the text box at the bottom");
        frame.add(welcome,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //action listener listens for enter key
        textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {

                //checks if player Ones name is set and sets player Twos name aswell
                if (!playerOneNameSet)
                {
                    playerOneName = textField.getText();
                    textField.setText("");
                    welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 2 in the text box at the bottom");
                    playerOneNameSet = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerTwoName = textField.getText();
                    textField.setText("");  
                    
                    //turning the nameSetUpDone to true as we are finished setting up the names
                    nameSetUpDone = true;
                    
                    // repainting as we want to update the screen
                    frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                    welcome.setText("Player One:" + playerOneName +" Player Two:" + playerTwoName + " Awaiting player one move");
                    
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: See: [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

Comment: Further to using `SplashScreen` .. `ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/riskimage.jpg");` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.